# SQL Server query takes longer with parameter than with constant string

Tags: sql-server, performance, parameters, database-performance

I'm facing a problem with MS SQL Server 2008 which is:

When I execute a query using a hard-coded string as a parameter, my query run fast but when I use a string parameter instead, the query takes longer!
Constant string query takes 1 second while the other takes 11 seconds.

Here are the codes bellow:

Constant string (1 second):

```
     SELECT * 
FROM   VIEWCONTENTS 
WHERE  COUNTRY = 'ZA' 
       AND CONTENTTYPE = 'A' 
       AND TASK = 'R23562';
```

Parameterized (11 seconds):

```
DECLARE @country AS CHAR(2); 

SET @country = 'ZA'; 

SELECT * 
FROM   VIEWCONTENTS 
WHERE  COUNTRY = @country 
       AND CONTENTTYPE = 'A' 
       AND TASK = 'R23562'
```

Comment: Google "parameter sniffing"....

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans? Also read this: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options

Comment: As the optimizer doesn't know the value of the local variable in the second query it is most likely changing the query plan to use a table/index scan rather than a seek.

Answer (score 3):

Use **OPTION (RECOMPILE)** at the end of your query. So:

```
DECLARE @country AS CHAR(2); 

SET @country = 'ZA'; 

SELECT * 
FROM   VIEWCONTENTS 
WHERE  COUNTRY = @country 
       AND CONTENTTYPE = 'A' 
       AND TASK = 'R23562'
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

What does this yield?

```
DECLARE @country AS VARCHAR(2); 
SET @country = 'ZA'; 

SELECT * 
FROM   VIEWCONTENTS 
WHERE  COUNTRY = @country 
       AND CONTENTTYPE = 'A' 
       AND TASK = 'R23562'
```

How about this?

```
DECLARE @country AS CHAR(2); 
DECLARE @country1 AS VARCHAR(2); 
SET @country = 'ZA';
SET @country1 = @country; 

SELECT * 
FROM   VIEWCONTENTS 
WHERE  COUNTRY = @country 
       AND CONTENTTYPE = 'A' 
       AND TASK = 'R23562'
```