# Why does parameterized query take much longer than non parametized

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, azure-sql-database, pyodbc, database-performance

I am using pyodbc with azure sql server

I had a query like this:

```
query = Update MyTable set MyDate = SYSDATETIME() where MyCol in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
cur.commit()
```

I changed this query to use parameters:

```
query = Update MyTable set MyDate = SYSDATETIME() where MyCol in (?,?,?)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query, ['val1','val2', 'val3'])
cur.commit()
```

The parameterized query is *much* slower.

There are some similar questions I have seen on this site ([SQL Server query takes longer with parameter than with constant string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496215/sql-server-query-takes-longer-with-parameter-than-with-constant-string))

I am trying some of the suggestions and not seeing any improvements.

More specifically I have tried adding `option(recompile)` and `option(recompile,use hint('DISABLE_PARAMETER_SNIFFING'))` but not seeing any improvements.

In the example I am inserting three values but in the business scenario it's more like 200.

Thanks all.

Comment: Try this pattern for replacing large IN lists (which are problematic) with a JSON array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617437/how-to-use-sql-parameters-with-in-clause-for-a-variable-number-of-values-with-py/57617543#57617543

Comment: What datatype are the parameters? If nvarchar but your column is varchar this can prevent an index seek in some collations.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft just gave that a go. Thank you. It did speed up the query tremendously. But the parameterized query now takes 26 seconds while the unparameterized takes a milisecond.

Comment: @MartinSmith the data type of MyCol is varchar, it's the primary key.

Comment: And in the query sent to the server what parameter datatype is pyodbc sending? You need to get the execution plan for that query to see how it looks and if there are any implicit casts on Mycol preventing a seek

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/376

Comment: @MartinSmith this solved my issue! Thank you! If you add this as an answer I would like to select it.